# How Do I Set the Page Title Dynamically?

Tags: seo, title

Is it possible to change the page title with code?

For example, let's say the page's name is "Book your Order", but I want to change it to "Book Order #123".

I Google'd a bit and looked here and didn't see anything.  Anyone know of a plugin or hack?

wp_title returns the page title but doesn't allow setting the page title:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title

Comment: Where would the value come from? what has in that page the value of #123 ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no documentation on it but you could always apply a filter to `the_title` like this:

```
add_filter('the_title','some_callback');
function some_callback($data){
    global $post;
    // where $data would be string(#) "current title"
    // Example:
    // (you would want to change $post->ID to however you are getting the book order #,
    // but you can see how it works this way with global $post;)
    return 'Book Order #' . $post->ID;
}
```

See these:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: This seems to override all titles. How do I override only the current title?

Comment: You would need to add a condition to the callback, e.g `if ($post->ID == 45) { ... }`

Comment: `the_title` filter no longer works in the latest versions of Wordpress, use `document_title_parts` or `pre_get_document_title` filters as detailed in other answers.

Answer (score 16):

As of Wordpress 4.4, you can use the Wordpress filter [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) to change the title.

Add the following to `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'my_custom_title');
function my_custom_title( $title ) {
  // $title is an array of title parts, including one called `title`

  $title['title'] = 'My new title';

  if (is_singular('post')) {
    $title['title'] = 'Fresh Post: ' . $title['title'];
  }

  return $title;
}
```

Comment: but where do you pass in the parameter to a filter?

Comment: The above function modifies the way `the_title()` and `get_the_title()` functions work - so no need to pass any parameters.

Answer (score 8):

For those wishing to change the document's `title` attribute, I found that using the `wp_title` filter no longer works. Instead, use [the `pre_get_document_title` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/):

```
add_filter("pre_get_document_title", "my_callback");
function my_callback($old_title){
    return "My Modified Title";
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268098/937377)

Comment: thanks for coming back years later to post this update.  I had been using wp_title in a plugin of mine for years and hadn't realized it was no longer working until now and your answer saved me a lot of effort.  So Thank you!

Comment: @MatthewLee Glad to hear it helped you :)

Answer (score 7):

When having Yoast enabled you need to override the title like so:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'custom_titles', 10, 1);
function custom_titles() {

  global $wp;
  $current_slug = $wp->request;

  if ($current_slug == 'foobar') {

    return 'Foobar';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Really depends if you're looking to display a custom title for the current page (i.e. the contents of the `<title></title>` tag in the header) or filter the title of pages in the page body or in listings.

In the former case (the title of the current page), try adding a filter for `wp_title()` like so:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

If you want to modify page titles across the board, filtering `the_title()` will do the trick:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

Comment: Actually in my experience you need to filter both `wp_title` and `the_title` to cover both.

Comment: I am not sure if its because of the deprecation but tis doesnt work for me. I have tried combinations and inline filters and the new apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', string $title )

Comment: sadly neither worked for me either.

Comment: This answer is nearly 6 years old; as the poster (and someone who doesn't actively work with WP anymore), I would suggest looking at the latest documentation instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using All In One Seo v4+, use this filter:

```
add_filter( 'aioseo_title', 'aioseo_filter_title' );

function aioseo_filter_title( $title ) {
   if ( is_singular() ) {
      return $title . 'some additional title content here';
   }
   return $title;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually the easiest way to do this is use one line of js.

Put the following code in the template:

```
<script>document.title = "<?php echo $new_title; ?>";</script>
```

This code doesn't has to be in the html header, it can be put in the html body.

Comment: This won't be good for SEO though.

Comment: @AlexCook You are definitely correct. I was working on a quick fix for something where SEO didn't matter. Now I totally forgot what this was used for. lol.