# Changing title of a page dynamically from within a plugin

Tags: plugins, title, get-the-title, wp-title

Every WordPress page can be described as having two titles:

1. The page/post title, which is displayed within the page/post via the `the_title()` function call
2. The html `<title></title>` tag that displays the title on top of the browser

I am writing a plugin which at one point should change the title of a page dynamically (well, it should change both titles described above).

So, for step 1 above, I found multiple solutions on Stack Overflow (such as [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46707/change-page-title-from-plugin) or [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33101/how-do-i-set-the-page-title-dynamically)). Those are great for only step 1 above.

For step 2, I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51479/setting-title-using-wp-title-filter) solution; in a nutshell, this is how it works:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'change_page_title');
function change_page_title ($title) {

    // Do some magic, and eventually modify $title then return it
    return $title;
}
```

But the suggested solution is not working for me; and by not working I mean that the filter is not calling the associated function. I am not sure what the problem is; is it because this filter is being called from within the plugin not the theme? (Just FYI, I do not have access to the theme files, so it has to be done from within the plugin).

How can I accomplish this? How can I change the browser title of a page dynamically from within a plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A post or page has only one title, the title tag `<title>` is the document title.

The filter `wp_title` filters the output of `wp_title()` function, which was used before to output the title of the document. In WordPress 4.1, the title-tag support in themes was introduced and [`wp_get_document_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) is used instead of `wp_title()`. So, if your theme supports `title-tag`, `wp_title` filter has not effect, but you can use a other filters:

[`pre_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/) to set a new title

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'cyb_change_page_title' );
function cyb_change_page_title () {

    return "Custom title";

}
```

[`document_title_separator`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) to filter the title separator

```
add_filter('document_title_separator', 'cyb_change_document_title_separator');
function cyb_change_document_title_separator ( $sep ) {

    return "|";

}
```

[`documente_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) to filter different parts of the title: title, page number, tagline and site name.

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'cyb_change_document_title_parts' );
function cyb_change_document_title_parts ( $title_parts ) {

    $title_parts['title'] = 'Custom title';
    $title_parts['page'] = 54;
    $title_parts['tagline'] = "Custom tagline";
    $title_parts['site'] = "My Site"; // When not on home page

    return $title_parts;

}
```

PD: You can use [`current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_theme_supports/) to check if theme supports `title-tag` or not.

Comment: but how to pass a pages unique meta data into the filter functions on a page-by-page basis?

Comment: You can use functions like [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/), `is_single()`, `is_singular()` and so on, to check the current page or post.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code on you page.php or page which you want to change
`<pre>
<title><?php wp_title(); ?> | <?php bloginfo(‘name’); ?></title>
</pre>`

Comment: You mean in the theme? I do not have access to the theme files.

Comment: worked. thank you so much